# 4d interpolation in python

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

So I have a 4d force field as in `x` `y` and `z` with a `Force` attached to each point.

I'm a a bit at a lost on how to interpolate this, I came across this though.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html

It looks like I can make an array of `x y z F` and then interpolate it but I'm really not too sure.

Anyone know any good libraries for python on how to do this?

Example input is:

```
x y z Force  
0 0 0 35  
0 0 1 32  
0 0 2 23  
...  
2 5 9 54
```

Comment: Can you add some sample input data to your post? It is impossible to give you a useful answer based on what you have written. You can generate random data of the same shape as your input if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The way you described it (x,y,z), this is a 3D field, not 4D.

The purpose of interpolation is to specify a field (in this case `Force`) at any point (x,y,z) 
even if you don't have a Force, at precisely that point (x,y,z).  Instead, you have the forces at a number of nearby points and you *interpolate* them to get a *meaningful* Force at point (x,y,z).  In 3D you would need a bilinear interpolation algorithm at the least, and coding it up (and keeping indices in order) is non-trivial.

In Python, you can use [Scipy's interpolation routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata).

Comment: Well no its a scalar field in 3d space so for every 3d point there is a scalar associated hence 4d.

Comment: Dimensionality of the field is what is defining the interpolation here. It would be 3D interpolation (not 6D) even if it was a 3-vector force at each point.

Comment: Ah thanks good to know that, right so if I understand this right can I use this griddata( (x,y,z) ,Force, (gridx,gridy,gridz), method='cubic') then it will give me the Force at gridx, gridy, gridz?

Answer (score 0):

So, if i understand you corret, you have the force given at some points and at others not and want to come up with an interpolation? 
At NMR the use of linear interpolation is till up to date. As an alternative, you can give splines a try, but thats more costly. But it mostly depends on the kind of your force - how fast is it going changing? Build your interpolation rouinte out of that.