# Interpolating unorganized 3D data to a spherical mesh using python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, data-fitting

Dear StackOverFlow users,

my problem is the following.

I have a set of points (around 1.e4) in a 3D space. For these points I know their spherical coordinates (r,theta,phi) and the corresponding value of density at each point (rho). The points are however not mapped to any grid, they are just unorganised in the space.
What I want to do is interpolate the values of density I have at each point to a uniform spherical mesh of my choice.

To do that I am trying to use the scipy.interpolate SmoothSphereBivariateSpline method. However, I believe the method only maps spherical coordinates at a fixed radius (I am not completely sure though).

So my first question is if there is a python interpolation method that I can use for my purpose.

Second, if the SmoothSphereBivariateSpline would work for my purpose, I would like to ask if someone could suggest the way to use it.
I am trying the following now:

```
#spherical mesh data
theta_mesh_num = 3
phi_mesh_num = 3
radius_mesh_num = 100

#read data from my data file
radius = rows_0[:,0]
theta = rows_0[:,2]
phi = rows_0[:,1]
density = rows_0[:,5] + 1.e-18

#interpolator object on the unorganised data                                                                                  
interpolator_density = SmoothSphereBivariateSpline(theta, phi, radius, w=density, s=len(density))

#setup spherical grid (uniform for the moment)                                                                                
array_theta = np.linspace(0., np.pi, theta_mesh_num)
array_phi = np.linspace(0., 2*np.pi, phi_mesh_num)
array_radius = np.linspace(np.min(radius), np.max(radius), radius_mesh_num)
grid_theta, grid_phi, grid_radius = np.meshgrid(array_theta, array_phi, array_radius)

#interpolate data on the grid                                                                                                 
data_inerp = interpolator_density(array_theta,array_phi,array_radius)
```

With this code I get the error below:

ValueError: 
No more knots can be added because the additional knot would (quasi)
coincide with an old one: s too small or too large a weight to an
inaccurate data point.
The weighted least-squares spline corresponds to the current set of
knots.

As I said, I am not sure if this is correct. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the impression that `SmoothSphereBivariateSpline` interpolates a function `r(theta,phi)`, i.e. a surface, i.e. 3D data, while you have 4D data `rho(r,theta,phi)`, right?

Comment: According to some comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409078/4d-interpolation-in-python) [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) may do the trick, but it might be necessary to convert it to `x,y,z`

Comment: That is correct @mikuszefski, I have a 4D data-cube. So as I suspected `SmoothSphereBivariateSpline` is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I took a look at `griddata` as well in the last couple of days, and, as you suggest, it would do the trick in Cartesian coordinates. However, if I interpolate to a Cartesian grid, then I will have to re-interpolate from Cartesian to Spherical (I want my data to be in a spherical grid). This will probably cause a greater level of approximation in the data. Therefore I'd like to avoid a double interpolation.

Comment: Some other suggestion?

Comment: Well , nobody says that you could not use directly `r,theta,phi`  in `griddata`. You only have to increase your dataset to take account for the periodicity in `phi` and `theta`

Comment: `griddata` is meant to work in Euclidean space, if I understand correctly. That means that in a curved system of coordinates it will try to interpolate not along the curved lines connecting points, but rather using the straight lines. I think this will yield a poor interpolation.

Comment: Am I correct on this?

Comment: I'd say you are right, but if you use `r,theta,phi` as Euclidean coordinates, that should somewhat work. The precision is different as this mapping changes the point density. And you will see differences in the interpolation in larger voids.

Comment: @mikuszefski can I use SmoothSphereBivariateSpline to construct a surface from random r(theta, phi) points? Random as in, they are not ordered or equally spaced.

Comment: What about fitting spherical harmonics?